# Outlook 2013 Addin not creating entry in HKEY_Local_Machine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, vsto, setup-deployment

I am using VIsual Studio 2013 to create Addin for Outlook 2013. My VSTO itself is creating a registry entry for HKCU. So the user who installed it can use the Addin. Since it is not creating a entry for HKLM , other users cannot see the Addin while the outlook is open in their own profile.

I went through all related topics tagged here and tried everything.But everything was disappointing for me.

I tried to create a set up project and created the registry path as below.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Addin_ID
```

But the Windows is creating the entry in the below location.

```
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Addin_ID
```

Just wondering if the VSTO alone could create an entry HKLM like it is creating an entry in HKCU now. Or it always need a set up project to create entry in HKLM. Please advise on how it can be done.

Your replies will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No, ClickOnce deployment is a user specific way of deploying. You don't needs administrator rights and that is the pretty part. The problem is: you have to install every user separately. Not only the registry is a problem here, the location of the files is too (the files are stored in the user profile).

You can use a [MSI package instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) if you want to install it for all users at once.

Comment: Hi Patrick.. I tried creating a MSI file to install the VSTO. BUT its creating the entry in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Addin_ID. My problem is that my client clears the users profile each time they logout of their profile. So whatever application s installed in the Machine level will be available for the user when he/she login again. I am wondering if their is any work around for this.

Comment: Did you follow the guide as in the post referenced?

Comment: Sorry, could you specify which guide you are talking about. I tried click once, MSI and install shield. All these are working, but only for current user. When I checked the registry, only HKCU is having an entry. And the MSI file could create an entry in  HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\Addin_ID . As my Outlook is 32bit and OS is 64 bit, windows force the MSI to create a entry inside Wow6432Node.

Comment: You should create a 64-bit installer for 64-bit systems.